# How do I have an API pickup where it left off after the request times out

Tags: python, api, soap

I'm still working on this cocktail app and I ran into another issue. After some time, the api call will drop after an hour; the api will only stay open for an hour. After that hour, I have to make a new api call. But I don't want to start all over when trying to pull data back. The data I'm using has over 300 thousand records in it to match, which on average takes about 10 hours to complete. Sorry, if this question does not make any sense I'm still new to coding and I'm doing my best!

For instance:

1. Make api call
2. Use data from csv file 300k records to get data back on
3. Retrieve the data back.
4. API connection drops--- Will need to make new api connection.
5. Make API call
6. Determine what data has been matched from csv file, then pick up from the next record that has not been matched.

Is there a way to make sure that when I have to get a new API key or when the connection drops, whenever the connection is made again it picks up where it left off?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "to get data back on" or "Retrieve the data back", or even by "Determine which data has been matched". I can't tell what's happening on the client versus the server. Whatever the case, if it's taking 10 hours to search through 300k records -- not that many -- then the app's architecture leaves a lot to be desired. Shouldn't that take more like a second or two?

Comment: @Noah that's what I thought... When I say, 'get data back on' I mean when it finds the match it will return matched data for that specific row it was passed. I don't know what's going on with the server but it just drops after an hour. So after an hour I have to reconnect and try to find where the last match received from the api, then start my loop on the next row. How do I get api to continue to where it left off?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want your API to have something like "sessions" that the client can disconnect and reconnect to.

Just some sort of session ID the server can use to reconnect you to whatever long running query it is doing.

It probably gets quite complex though. The query may finish when no client is connected and so the results need to be stored somewhere keyed by the session id so that when the API reconnects it can get the results.

PS. 10 hours to match 300K records? That is a crazy amount of time ! I'd be doing some profiling on that match algorithm.

Comment: I am storing the results in a list. How do I build this session to do that?

Comment: Without (a lot) more details it is hard to help further. I'd be inclined to store the results in a DB indexed by the session id - but then you also need to consider security - what stops person B getting person A's results just by hijacking the session id.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed this. How much detail do you need? The server I'm connecting to keeps bombing out.